# Parsing dblp.xml with java DOM/SAX

Tags: java, dom

I am trying to parse dblp.xml in java to get the author names/title/year etc, but since the file is huge (860MB), I cannot use DOM/SAX on the complete file.

So I split the file into multiple small files of around 100MB each.

Now each file contains various (thousands of) nodes like this:

```
<dblp>
<inproceedings mdate="2011-06-23" key="conf/aime/BianchiD95">
<author>Nadia Bianchi</author>
<author>Claudia Diamantini</author>
<title>Integration of Neural Networks and Rule Based Systems in the Interpretation of Liver     Biopsy Images.</title>
<pages>367-378</pages>
<year>1995</year>
<crossref>conf/aime/1995</crossref>
<booktitle>AIME</booktitle>
<url>db/conf/aime/aime1995.html#BianchiD95</url>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-60025-6_152</ee>
</inproceedings>
</dblp>
```

100MB should be readable in DOM, I am assuming, but the code stops after roughly 45k lines. Here is the java code I am using:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "null"})
public List<dblpModel> readConfigDOM(String configFile) {
    List<dblpModel> items = new ArrayList<dblpModel>();
    List<String> strList = null;
    dblpModel item = null;

    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File(configFile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("incollection");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            item = new dblpModel();
            strList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                strList = getTagValueString("title", eElement);
                System.out.println(strList.get(0).toString());

                strList = getTagValueString("author", eElement);
                System.out.println("Author : " + strList.size());
                for(String s: strList) {
                    System.out.println(s);

                }
            }
            items.add(item);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}


private static String getTagValueString(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    String temp = "";
    StringBuffer concatTestSb = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).getLength();

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            NodeList nl = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(i).getChildNodes();
            if (nl.getLength() > 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) {
                    concatTestSb.append(nl.item(j).getTextContent());
                }
            } else {
                temp = nl.item(0).getNodeValue();
                concatTestSb.append(temp);
                if (len > 1) {
                    concatTestSb.append("*");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return concatTestSb.toString();
}
```

Any help? I have tried using STAX api for parsing large documents also, but that also

Comment: You'll get better answers if you say exactly what "the code stops" means. Does `readConfigDOM()` return, or does it hang? If it hangs, what line does it hang at (you can run under a debugger and/or get a thread dump).

Comment: Incidentally, SAX would have no problem with a large file.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to just get the details out, the just use a BufferedReader to read the file as a text file. If you want, throw in some regex.

if using mysql is an option, you may be able to get it to do the heavy lifting through it's [XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fuss too much about the xml format. It is not terribly useful anyway. Just read it as text file and parse the lines as string. You can then export the data to a csv and use it the way you want from that point.
Unfortunately xml is not very efficient for large documents. I did something similar here for a research project:
http://qualityofdata.com/2011/03/27/dblp-for-sql-server/